# web.config changes for publishing WCF service into Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, azure

I have a WCF service which works fine offline
However, when I publish it into Azure, it doesn't

http://ties532.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc

Notice `<customErrors mode="off"/>` in my web.config, which actually did not make any difference about error displaying...

I know that I need to make some changes to the web.config file, how it says here:

[HOW TO FIX ‘RUNTIME/SERVER ERROR’ REDIRECT ISSUES](http://denepalmer.azurewebsites.net/index.php/how-to-fix-runtimeserver-error-redirect-issues-when-adding-azure-acs-authentication-to-an-asp-net-project/)

But the method above is only for Visual Studio 2012, and I have 2015.

**Question:** How do I define final URI for the service (I guess, it will solve the problem) in Visual Studio 2015, manually?

My web.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace>
  <listeners>
    <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      name="AzureDiagnostics">
    </add>
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
<!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />-->
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
-->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 16.12**

Azure website sucks. Spent 2 hours for repairing another problem - deployed without mistakes through the VS.

Solved through removing one string from web.config and adding " encoding="utf-8" " to the root element (final config is above).

***To access your service from remote desktop - go to app where you can see your service statistics (inside of the remote desktop, don't remember the name) and pick the IP from there. Localhost did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a remote desktop connection to connect on your cloud service VM.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-enable-remote-desktop/

Then use the VM Internet Explorer to test your website, I think you will have a more verbose error log.

Regards,

Florent.

Comment: hi. im in the IE inside of machine. if I use the same address (http://ties532.cloudapp.net/) it does not change anyhow, same error log. i guess, i need to use the localhost address? where do I get that?

Comment: Tried that, as well as 127.0.0.1/Service1.svc. Not working at all.

Comment: I found IP of the server in the server monitoring app and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change off to Off - mode only accepts On|Off|RemoteOnly

Comment: that was a part of puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

There is a common problem in Cloud Service project with referenced DLL not installed on the VM.

In your Project references, can you configure all references with "Copy Local" property set to "TRUE" and then redeploy to Azure?